# OnAdapterChangedListener of ViewPager

Tags: android, interface, android-viewpager

In my app, I wanted to implement an `OnAdapterChangedListener` but found out that it is actually a private interface in `ViewPager`. My questions are:-

> 1.) Why did the developers make it a private interface?
>
> 2.) What are the alternatives to implement an event listener when `setAdapter` is used?

Comment: the answer to your second question mostly depends on your actual goal... why do you exactly need the `onAdapterChangedListener`?

Comment: @BartekLipinski I have created 2 different adapters (single view and multiple view) in my app and by toggling a button, I am changing the adapters.

Comment: Which version of support library are you using? Because for me this `OnAdapterChangedListener` seems public...

Comment: `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`
its from the revision 23.4 v4 support library

Answer (score 0):

You do this when the function of the method only relates to the containing class and even then its not really something you have to do. This would be one of those coding preference things. So as an example you would have other classes that want to implement Ione and you would want those other classes to know that Ione is related to class a.

public class SomeOtherClass implements a.Ione {
 ...
}

Comment: right.. that sort of answers my first question. But can you tell me why on the developers page [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnAdapterChangeListener.html) it shows **public static interface**, whereas in the source code it is **interface**

Comment: public static is on the developer page because it is actual declaration. If you use public static on that interface in the code, it will behave same. you can say it is redundent.